# What is the image-dired regexp for line-end?

Tags: regular-expressions, image-dired

In [image-dired](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Image_002dDired.html) I use `M-x` `image-dired-mark-tagged-files` to mark files containing a tag using regexp. e.g. `jan`. **The problem** is that `jane` is marked as well.

What regex do I need to mark `jan` but *not* `jane`?

Input:

```
/foo/IMG_2022.JPG;jan
/foo/IMG_2023.JPG;jane
```

While `jan\$` works in regexp-builder, it returns 0 results if used in `M-x` `image-dired-mark-tagged-files`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `jan\b` (in Lisp code, that's `jan\\b`).

That says to match `jan` when the `n` is on a word boundary.

Comment: Any ideas to match the tag `bar` but not not the tag `foo bar`? Tried `\^bar`. Will gladly open another question.

Comment: One question per post, please. But you have to decide what exactly you want to exclude from matching before `bar`, and create a regexp that specifies that.